# funcion para un consecutivo en php

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día¡

Tengo un problema.
Me pidieron que haga una función para contabilizar un consecutivo.

mi campo de la tabla en MySQL se llama contador
Para eso al agregar un cliente se tiene que poner el consecutivo en dicho campo

espero me puedan ayudar

quedo atento a sus opiniones saludos

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema, lo que quieres saber es cuantos registros existen y al mismo tiempo que los cuente ?, cuando agregas un nuevo registro se actualice y te despliegue el nuevo total ?

Comment: Disculpa no me explique bien. El campo contador tiene un numero el cual va aumentando conforme se agregan clientes. tiene campos que determinan un rango que se aplica al cliente y cuando se agrega el cliente deseo determinar en que rango va y una vez que se asigna el rango el contador debe incrementar el cliente agregado a dicho rango

Comment: el rango de que tipo es?

Comment: Es de tipo int hay rango de 1 a 999999 y otros 4 mas del mismo tipo (Con otro rango respectivamente)

Comment: pudieras hacerlo desde la consulta que te traega el numero del rango mas alto

Comment: el problema es que el contador debe aumentar automaticamente cuando se ingrese un cliente nuevo y debe incrementar en su rango propio pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: tu contador es como la llave primaria ?.. Seria mas fácil si pones el código de donde te quedaste para ayudarte

Comment: No me he explicado bien. tengo 2 tablas, una se llama def_cliente con un campo no_cartera el cual tiene un numero es el valor que va dentro del rango de mi tabla que se llama def_consecutivo en el cual hay campo de rango,desde, hasta, contador; cuando se agregue un cliente en mi tabla de consecutivo se debe aumentar el contador de acuerdo al rango que tiene. Funcion que me da el ultimo valor del contador  `public function getConsecutiveByRange($rango)
    { $sql ="SELECT contador FROM def_consecutivo WHERE rango_numeros=:rango"; return $this->getResponseQueryOne($sql,["rango"=>$rango]);  }`

Comment: el contador no es llava primaria